# Oracle rename a column with a selected value

Tags: oracle, ddl

I need to rename a table column giving it a new name that is selected from another table, like this (I'm using a fake code to let you understand):

```
Alter table CUSTOMERS
Rename column OCCUPATION to (select ITA_NAME from TAGS where ENG_NAME = 'occupation')
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Read up on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: It is possible, but it is not a best practice. Why would you store column names in a table? It's hard to think of a valid use case for such tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem like a wise thing to want to do but you can use dynamic SQL

```
declare
  l_new_column_name varchar2(30);
begin
  select ITA_NAME 
    into l_new_column_name
    from TAGS 
   where ENG_NAME = 'occupation';

  execute immediate 'Alter table CUSTOMERS ' ||
                    '  Rename column OCCUPATION to ' || l_new_column_name;
end;
```

Note that this code does nothing to prevent SQL injection attacks.  You'd probably want to at least use the `dbms_assert` package to ensure that `l_new_column_name` doesn't contain anything malicious.